# Docker running both Yarn update and npm update on docker-compose up

Tags: node.js, docker

I am running a docker container that is containing my backend code as a volume:

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  auth:
    container_name: ${AUTH_CONTAINER}
    build: ./modules/auth
    working_dir: /usr/app
    command: "npm install && npm start"
    volumes:
      - ../backend/modules/auth:/usr/app
    expose:
      - 9229
    ports:
      - 9229:9229
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY entrypoint.sh .

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Entrypoint:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
exec "$@"
```

when I run docker-compose up, the first step is always to run yarn. I get an error saying that I should not use both npm and yarn, because I currently am using npm for the project. Is there a way to have node:alpine only use npm only (I know its installed) and then call npm install when docker-compose up is ran?

EDIT: image of console: [image: console image]

EDIT2: Package.json

```
{
  "name": "auth",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: When `node:alpine` image is built, [it runs `yarn --version`](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/769695552abd81267f562517b40407c64039e36a/15/alpine3.11/Dockerfile#L95). That's all it does with `yarn`.

Comment: @Styx in my console, it runs: `yarn install v1.22.5`. and then a yarn.lock file appears with dependencies- which I am assuming belongs to node:alpine. I had added a picture of the console above.

Comment: Show `package.json`, please.

Comment: Can you do these steps in your Dockerfile, and remove the `volumes:`?  What benefit does your setup bring over directly using Node on the host?

Comment: @Styx I posted my package.json. 

@David Maze well, I plan on dockerizing multiple microservices. So I figure docker-compose (meaning I can run multiple containers) is something that I want to use. The `volumes:` points directly to my project files under modules/auth so if anything changes- then it rebuilds itself. What blows my mind, is that we I dont have anything in my code referencing yarn at all :/ I thought it might be coming from the node:alpine container- however @Styx said that it does not :/

Comment: I even tried building the docker container, and then running it with Docker-Compose and it still runs yarn install.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that gets to this point- and is wondering why this is happening. Ensure that you run the `docker-compose -- build` **FIRST** before running `docker-compose up` that is the problem I was running into.

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY entrypoint.sh /

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/entrypoint.sh"]
```

entrypoint:

```
exec "$@"
```

docker-compose:

```
version: '3'

services:
  auth:
    container_name: "Auth"
    build: "./auth"
    working_dir: /usr/app
    command: "npm start"
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=local
    volumes:
      - ../backend/modules/auth:/usr/app
    expose:
      - 9299
    ports:
      - 9229:9229
```